# I am getting compilation error for posix_spawnp function on Android-ndk

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I am using Ubuntu Linux and Android (android-ndk-r21d). When I am compiling my code with ndk-build, I am getting compilation error for posix_spawnp function call. I have included the header <spawn.h> for this function. I am unable to figure what compilation and Link flags I should use for this function in my Android.mk file. Is this function supported on Android-ndk ?

```
alc@alc:~/src/ForkBench(master)$ ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : forkBench <= forkBench.c
jni/../forkBench.c:61:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'posix_spawnp' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                status = posix_spawnp(&pid, TRUEAPP, NULL, NULL, launch_argv, NULL);
                         ^
jni/../forkBench.c:90:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'posix_spawnp' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                status = posix_spawnp(&pid, TRUEAPP, NULL, NULL, launch_argv, NULL);
                         ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [/home/alc/android-ndk-r21d-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r21d/build/core/build-binary.mk:476: obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/forkBench/__/forkBench.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The functions in spawn.h are only available on Android P and later (API level 28).

Comment: Micheal thanks for your suggestions. I changed the value of APP_PLATFORM := android-28 in Application.mk file and it successfully compiled.